Power Automate "Create Connection" Action token does not authenticate
We are trying to automate power platform deployment between different environments and we are brought to create connections using a power automate flow.
I have a very basic power automate flow that creates a connection to "Excel Online Business connector"
Power Automate flow setup
{ "status": "Error", "target": "Token", "error": { "code": "Unauthenticated", "message": "This connection is not authenticated." } 
Any ideas on how to fix this?
